# How to: "svn checkout --depth=empty" functionality in perforce

Tags: svn, perforce, svn-checkout

I want to upload some files/artifacts into perforce - the size of my content is about 100MB, while the parent of the folder that my code will be getting uploaded to is about 20GB in size. Over the WAN, I can just about forget getting this done in any reasonable amount of time.

Is there any way in perforce to checkout the parent directory with nothing in it - similar to the function provided by svn:

```
cd /tmp/toupload
svn checkout --depth=empty svn://path/to/parent-directory
```

... so that, after I have checked out the parent directory, I can do the following:

```
cd /tmp/toupload/parent-directory
tar xvf /tmp/toupload.tar
svn add mydirectory
svn commit -m "Adds mydirectory to version control" .
```

Is there a similar feature in perforce?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're doing in svn, in Perforce this is:

```
cd /tmp/toupload
p4 client (set up your client Root and View to indicate where your files go)
p4 add ...
p4 submit
```

The "checkout" step in Perforce would be a "p4 sync", but that's not a prerequisite for doing "p4 add" of new files, so you can just skip that part.

Comment: Are you sure it is as simple as that, without downloading any specific directory? Between "p4 client" and "p4 add", isn't there a step to download the directory into which my code will get uploaded to?

I just tried it locally, and it didn't work - I get the following error:
    Path '/cygdrive/d/P4/ubuild_OZ\personal/abc.txt' is not under client's root 'D:/P4/ubuild_OZ'.

Which sort of makes sense - to which directory in the depot does "personal" belong to? That information needs to be downloaded from the version-control tool and only then can Perforce perform any scm action on it. Right?

Comment: All that information lives on the server and is edited when you run "p4 client".  The "Root" in your client spec is the root of the files you're working on, and the "View" maps the depot namespace to the client namespace (which starts at the Root on your local system).  If you expand your example with the actual local path of the files and the actual depot path where they go, I can show you exactly what the client view should look like.